# What does 'lm' mean in the lmplot() in seaborn?

Tags: regression, visualization, seaborn

I was learning `seaborn`, but could not find the full name of `seaborn.lmplot`. What is 'l' and 'm' in the name 'lmplot'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"lm" = "linear model". As reported in the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html):

> Plot data and regression model fits across a FacetGrid. [...] It is intended as a convenient interface to fit regression models across conditional subsets of a dataset.

Comment: The documentation does not use the phrase 'linear model'.